# Automated tools to migrate struts 1 to struts 2

Tags: java, spring, migration, struts

Is anyone aware of automated tools to migrate the application from Struts1 to Struts2?

We would like to Migrate to Spring4.

Since struts 1 is not compatible with spring 4, planning on converting the application from Struts1 to Struts2 and then slowly migrate to Spring4 by making it working parallel in Struts2 and Spring4.
Any thoughts?

Comment: I think It will be better integrate Spring with Struts 1.

Comment: Its a huge application, have to enhance the existing application in struts and migrate to spring in parallel...

Comment: What do you mean by "migrate to spring". Spring MVC or just Spring IoC and database support?

Comment: Automated tools will never exist but you can try searching Google.

Comment: S1 and S2 is totally different frameworks. It is like asking to automate migration from X to Psi.

Comment: @Aleksandr M I understand, am trying to figure out any easy way to do this.

Comment: @v.ladynev, Spring MVC